# Streaming to the Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, http, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to write a light-weight `HTTP` server in my app to `feed` dynamically generated `MP3` data to the built-in `Android` `MediaPlayer`.  I am not permitted to store my content on the `SD card`.

My input data is essentially of an infinite length.  I tell `MediaPlayer` that its data source should basically be something like `"http://localhost/myfile.mp3"`.  I've a simple server set up that waits for `MediaPlayer` to make this request.  However, `MediaPlayer` isn't very cooperative.  At first, it makes an `HTTP GET` and tries to grab the whole file.  It times out if we try and simply dump data into the `socket` so we tried using the `HTTP` Range header to write data in chunks.  `MediaPlayer` doesn't like this and doesn't keep requesting the subsequent chunks.

Has anyone had any success streaming data directly into `MediaPlayer`?  Do I need to implement an `RTSP` or `Shoutcast` server instead?  Am I simply missing a critical `HTTP header`?  What strategy should I use here?

Comment: i know it late. but this is for those who end up here in the future. this [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback/5432091#5432091) has code to start with.

Comment: Did you also use this approach to playback video files? Did it perform the same as audio files?

Comment: Hey Rob have you got any workaround for the issue? can you share sample code ?

Answer (score 4):

> The `HTTP` Server was indeed hosted on the phone itself.  It was very
>   simple: just a `thread` listening on a socket for an `HTTP GET`
>   request.  When it got the `HTTP` request, it would one a `new socket`,
>   write back some `HTTP` headers and start dumping the `MP3` audio data
>   back to the `socket`.  This `HTTP` server didn't do anything else.
>
> The `Android Media Player` was playing the music as I was streaming to
>   it.  The `Media Player` behaved very poorly if its playback `buffer`
>   was emptied while it was playing audio.  It was very important for me
>   to make sure my `HTTP` server kept writing data into that `socket`. I
>   moved bytes into the socket in small chunks (10 kB). The headers on my
>   `HTTP` response ended up looking like this:
>
> ```
> // Build response headers
> StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
> sb.append( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
> sb.append( "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n");
> sb.append( "Connection: close\r\n" );
> sb.append( "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n" );
> sb.append( "Content-Length: " + totalFileSize + "\r\n" );
> sb.append( "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=xxxxx.mp3\r\n\r\n");
> ```
>
> As long as I kept the pipe stoked, the `Android Media Player` kept
>   consuming it without complaint.  Playing audio only required one
>   request and response.  It ended up working pretty well.

Comment: Any chance the full code is hosted anywhere? I'm trying to do the same with live video coming from the MediaRecorder + Camera and am exhausted with chasing down different attempts and libraries. If not, what size bounty would it take to add more detail here?